Program running in docker with --runtime=nvidia --gpus don't see GPU
I need help debugging.
I am running a program (DaVinci Resolve) in a docker. I have the NVidia runtime installed, and I am running with docker run --runtime=nvidia --gpus.... Running nvidia-smi does see the GPU (but not the processes running on it):
Mon Jul 29 08:06:12 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.90.07              Driver Version: 550.90.07      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti     Off |   00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   55C    P0             60W /  200W |    1186MiB /   8192MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

When I run the application, it complains there is no GPU it can use. I need help debugging this.
